# Page without answer(s) in Stack Overflow

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, answers, pagination

I read this great post, *[List of freely available programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)*, in Stack Overflow. When I look at the 11th page, it looks like this;

[image]

There are no answers on page 11. But page 11 exists.

Is this a bug or is there something wrong in my computer?

```
Firefox 3.6.17
Windows 7 32 bit
```

Comment: Please don't use code formatting when there is no code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug happened because we use a denormalized `AnswerCount` field we store with each question...and while this field is correct, it doesn't account for deleted answers.

Due to other changes we made in speeding up the question page, this is now trivial to fix though...so starting in the next build **we'll show the correct total answer count and paging controls** for users who can't see deleted content.

Comment: When will the next build take place? Also, will you show the pages for 10K members who can see the deleted answers?

Answer (score 17):

All of them are deleted on page 11, but yes, you shouldn't see the page 11 link

Comment: Are deleted answers also the cause of a similar issue reported earlier today?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93467/displaying-x-amount-of-results-per-page-with-x-results-shows-link-to-empty-page

Comment: @Rick, I indeed see page 2 link, but deleted questions are not listed for 10k users, So I can't figured that out myself if that is the same case or not. Probably moderators can but I am not sure.

Comment: This is still unresolved.  [The page is still blank](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books?page=11&tab=votes#tab-top).