# Let's get rid of this [page]

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [page](/questions/tagged/page) tag has 8 questions, no wiki or excerpt.  There are *many* other tags for what it could be talking about:  [homepage](/questions/tagged/homepage), [frontpage](/questions/tagged/frontpage), [profile-page](/questions/tagged/profile-page), [tags-page](/questions/tagged/tags-page), [etc](/questions/tagged/etc)... [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93502/page-without-answers-in-stack-overflow) question, for instance, could've used the [pagination](/questions/tagged/pagination) tag instead of [page](/questions/tagged/page).
Thoughts?  Should we get rid of this [page](/questions/tagged/page)?

Comment: *clicked etc ... disappointed*

Comment: @rene I knew you'd click that, that's why I put it there.  Wouldn't it be [tag:fun] if Meta had a [etc] tag?

Comment: To me, it seems that all but one can just have the [[tag:page]] tag removed. It's covered by other tags - [[tag:navigation]] or [[tag:design]]. Only [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311109/how-many-pages-of-philosophy-are-there) might need to be retagged as [[tag:navigation]]

Comment: @VLAZ that could do fine with the pagination tag.

Comment: @Luuklag agreed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The ambiguous [page](/questions/tagged/page) tag has been subjected to the withering fire of Trogdor:

[image]